# Are "this.props" and "this.state" functions?

Tags: reactjs

React docs claims that `render()` method is a function of `this.props` and `this.state` (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html):

> `render()` methods are written declaratively as functions of `this.props` and `this.state`. The framework guarantees the UI is always consistent with the inputs.

What does it mean? `this.props` and `this.state` are object for sure, not functions:

```
this.props === Object {}
this.state === Object {data: Array[0]}
```

So how to understand that?

Answer (score 2):

What is meant is that, **conceptually**, `render()` is a function of `this.props` and `this.state`. Think of it in this way, with the same `this.props` and the same `this.state` the result of `render()` should always be the same.

It is not written like `render(props, state)`, but conceptually that is the way one should think of a component!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I understand (I just wrote the sentence in form of a function to understand it conceptually)

The method `this.render()` = function(`this.props`, `this.state`) 
where `this.props` and `this.state` are objects.

which means `render()` method is dependant on `this.props` and `this.state`. Whenever, any of these changes, the `render()` method is called and a the component is re-rendered.

However, if we wish to call the `render()` method manually when some data changes deep within an state or a props object without changing the object itself, we can do so by calling [`forceUpdate()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate). Here the `render()` method conceptually becomes a function of the method that calls `forceUpdate()` as well as `this.props` and `this.state`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Component Specs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html):

> When [render is] called, it should examine this.props and this.state and return a
>   single child element.

If `render()` was placed outside of the component, it would look like:

`function render(props, state)`

Since `props` and `state` is all `render()` needs to render.

Answer (score 0):

:? I went through the linked page and didn't come across this claim, direct or otherwise. However, the statement simply means that the method reads the props and state in order to give out an element.